# How to select all occurrences between a positive lookbehind and lookahead?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I want to learn how to capture all occurrences of a character (e.g., `-`) between `(?<=...)` and `(?=...)`.

Suppose I have the following text:

```
- [abc!word1-word2-word3]
- word1-word2-word3
```

I aim to create a single capture group containing all `-` only if the string starts with `[abc!` and ends with `]`.

I tried the following (e.g., see [demo here](https://regex101.com/r/7AUO8V/1)) using the `gm` options and the `PCRE2` flavor:

```
(?<=\[abc!).*(-).*(?=\])
```

However, only the last occurrence of `-` is matched, as shown below.

[image]

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: You cannot "*create a single capture group containing all -*". I think you want to replace/remove the hyphens between `\[abc!` and the next `]`. So, use ``(?:\G(?!\A)|\[abc!)[^][-]*\K-(?=[^][]*])``, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IGwYhk/1).

Comment: Ah, okay, this explains it. Indeed, I was aiming to replace the hyphens. Do you mind turning your comment into an answer? Then I can accept it. Thanks, @WiktorStribiżew!

Comment: You could match the first (rather than last) hyphen with `(?<=\[abc!).*?(-)(?=.*?\])` (`.*?` matches the fewest characters necessary to satisfy the regular expression) but you may be overlooking the fact that the regex engine evaluates the *entire* expression (including `(?<=\[abc!)`) when attempting to make a subsequent match. It is for that reason that `\G(?!\A)` is needed, as @Wiktor shows. Note that many regex engines do not support `\G` and/or `\K`.

Comment: A small thing: your question would have been clearer had you not expressed your regular expression in extended mode (`/x`) (which removes whitespace and comments in a preprocessing step), as the reader must read further before realizing you have specified that mode. Moreover, as the expression is so short, and you have not included comments, the use of extended mode does not make  the expression any easier to read.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, thanks for the tips. I (1) updated the regular expression in the question, (2) the demo link to remove the extended flag, and (3) mentioned the flavor and options used before the expression. Indeed, the `\G` and `\K` did not help much due to a lack of support. I am still wondering whether this can be done differently...

Comment: Regarding your (3) I don't follow what you mean by, "...the `\G` and `\K` did not help much due to a lack of support" considering that those directives are supported by the PCRE2 engine. Also, there is no point in simply matching the hyphens (unless you are just counting them), but I recall that before editing you said you were replacing matches. If that's the case you might find it helpful to broaden your question and include a tag with the language you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace each individual hyphen betwee `[abc!` and the next (closest) `]` char using

```
(?:\G(?!\A)|\[abc!)[^][-]*\K-(?=[^][]*])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IGwYhk/1).

*Details*:

- `(?:\G(?!\A)|\[abc!)`  - either the end of the previous successful match (`\G(?!\A)`, see [this `\G` reference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html)) or (`|`) `[abc!` string (`\[abc!`)
- `[^][-]*` - zero or more chars other than `[`, `]` and `-`
- `\K` - a [*match reset operator*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) that discards the text matched so far from the match memory buffer
- `-` - a hyphen
- `(?=[^][]*])` - a [*positive lookahead*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that makes sure there are zero or more chars other than square brackets followed with a `]` char immediately to the right of the current location.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of ways to accomplish your objective if you are using a regex engine that does not support `\G`, provided certain conditions hold.

**Case 1: Your regex engine supports variable-length positive lookbehinds (C#'s engine, for example)**

You can use

```
(?<=\[abc!.*)-(?=(?:(?!\[abc!).)*])
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/F1sNr9/1)

This regular expression can be broken down as follows.

```
(?<=          # begin positive lookbehind
  \[abc!      # match literals
  .*          # match >= 0 characters other than line terminators
)             # end positive lookbehind
-             # match a literal
(?=           # begin a positive lookahead
  (?:         # begin a non-capture group
    (?!       # begin a negative lookahead
      \[abc!  # match a literal
    )         # end negative lookahead
    .         # match a character other than a line terminator
  )*          # end the non-capture group and execute it zero or more times
  ]           # match a literal
)             # end positive lookahead
```

**Case 2: It is known that every right bracket in the string is preceded in the string by `'[abc!'`, with no intervening right brackets**

```
-(?=(?:(?!\[abc!).)*])
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/h39GL1/1)

Notice that this regular expression is the same as the preceding one except the postive lookbehind has been dropped.